# Which requests should have the P3P header?

Tags: privacy, p3p

I am adding in a P3P header for privacy into a site, and was wondering if the header should be attached to HTML pages only, or to all responses (such as images, css and script)?

I currently have the header attached to all responses, but wanted to confirm if this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

The P3P header should be passed back on pages that write private information, such as cookies. The header can be passed back on static resources, but I doubt IE does anything with it. If you make an application-wide P3P header injection, then things should still work fine.

In my case for a Grails application in an IFRAME, I had to inject the headers early in the request cycle when the JSESSIONID was first assigned so that IE would store the cookie at the proper time.